# Solving a problem merging from trunk to branch in svn

Tags: svn, merge, conflict, tree-conflict

I have a problem when merging from the trunk into a development branch in an SVN tree.

The history of the project is this. It started with just a single trunk. About revision 207, the first branch was created. Then, at revision 331, the branch of interest was split off from the trunk.

We're now at revision 384. Most of the changes between 331 have been made on the branch of interest, but a few have independently been made on the trunk.

So that the branch stays in tune with the trunk, I wanted to merge from the trunk into it. So I duly did so:

```
svn merge ^/trunk .
```

However, I find that all manner of conflicts are popping up. A few conflicts I might understand, but almost all directories and files in the tree are affected.

What makes it worse is that most of these purported conflicts are actually changes that were committed to the trunk between 207 and 331, and are therefore already incorporated in the branch, having been there since the branch was split off from the trunk.

What's worse than that is that a number of the supposed conflicts are tree conflicts, involving files that were deleted or renamed, again between 207 and 331. Because they don't exist on the branch any more, and indeed shouldn't exist there, I can't see any way to resolve the problem.

A fix is complicated because for almost all files, the branch is correct, and so a merge in, followed by accepting the branch copy, leaves me with nothing to commit, so the server never gets the hint that the merge has in fact been carried out.

I've tried several things to fix it:

```
svn cleanup
```

It seemed to me that this didn't do anything pertinent.

```
svn checkout ^/branches/branch-of-interest new-local-copy-of-branch-of-interest
```

The problem persisted into the new copy of the checkout.

```
svn merge --record-only -r207:331 ^/trunk .
```

Interestingly enough, the supposedly "record-only" merge also tried to change the files in my local copy!

```
svn merge ^/trunk .
```

This generated a whole pile of conflicts and tree conflicts, even after I'd fought with the record-only merge, painstakingly resolving the changes it (the record-only merge) applied.

I should also say that when I started, my client was running 1.6.17 and the server 1.4.6. However, the server has since been upgraded to 1.6.17 too, and the problem persists.

Is there any way people have found to solve this problem? Doing a full merge and resolving files one by one would be incredibly time-consuming, and at this point - for obvious reasons - I don't even have confidence that the next time my SVN wouldn't just try to pull the same thing on me all over again.

Comment: You might look through the logs for something weird on the trunk. I saw a similar problem once when the trunk was removed and then restored via a merge.

Comment: Thanks John. Actually, I suspect it may be because the SVN repository database is still in 1.4 format, and is therefore unable to keep track of merges. I've contacted the repo maintainer, asking him to upgrade it. I'll see if that solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the problem lay in the database version associated with the repository. Even after the client and server had been upgraded to the latest version, the database was still in an old format that didn't track merges.

Upgrading to the latest database version solved the problem and allowed me to merge with no trouble. Particularly, we used these commands on the machine hosting the server and repo:

```
svnadmin upgrade /path/to/repository
svn-populate-node-origins-index /path/to/repository
```